# JSPM optimizing caching

Tags: angularjs, caching, npm, browser-cache, jspm

I've finished setting up my workflow to use JSPM and currently creates a production bundle with 2 large injected and hashed files main-{hash}.min.css main-{hash}.min.js

My question is, is it more efficient to separate the 3rd party dependencies from the main.js file (Angular, jQuery, etc) into its own vendors.js file?

My reasoning is that the vendors file is likely to not change much and users can maintain a valid cached version of that file while any small changes to the source files going into main.js will force the users to redownload the new main.js file without downloading the large dependency files again.

What's the best way to optimize caching and prevent excessive data use with a JSPM setup like this?

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage to serve your 3rd party dependencies from another bundle, is to improve the speed of bundling.

As you said, vendors files are likely to not change much, so you could bundle your app on its own, and only run both bundles when 3rd party dependencies are updated.

In both case, all those files are being served to your html page.

The vendor bundle would probably stay cached in browser as it rarely updated.